# Reading data file gives - severe(408) subscript is larger than the upper bound

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to read a four column data file. However, because I'm having so much trouble, I'm just trying to read a single column of integers. Here is my code:

```
   program RFF_Simple
    implicit none
    ! Variables
    character(len = 100):: line_in 
    character(len = :), allocatable :: filename 
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: weight,numbers    
    real, dimension(:), allocatable :: fm, fc 
    integer :: iostat_1, iostat_2 
    integer :: lun, length, index    


!    Body of RFF_Simple
!    filename = 'data.txt' 
    filename = 'data_test.txt'
    iostat_1 = 0 
    iostat_2 = 0 
    length = 0          
    open(newunit = lun, file = filename, status = 'old', iostat = iostat_1) 

    !Count how many lines are in the file (length) 
    if (iostat_1 == 0) then         
        do while(iostat_2 == 0)                  
            read(lun, '(a)', iostat = iostat_2)  line_in        
            if (iostat_2 == 0) then                 
                length= length + 1                 
            endif             
        enddo
    endif            
    rewind(lun)

    allocate(numbers(length)) !Allocate arrays to have same length as number of lines 
    iostat_1 = 0 !Reset 
    iostat_2 = 0 
    index = 1 !This whole thing is confusing so I don't know whether starting from 1 or 0 is better....      
    if (iostat_1 == 0) then         
        do while(iostat_2 == 0)                                                   
            if(iostat_2 == 0) then                                                     
                read(lun,*, iostat = iostat_2) numbers(index) !This crashes the program (Severe 408)            
                index = index + 1 
            endif
        enddo
    endif

    write(*,*) 'Press Enter to Exit' 
    read(*,*) 
    end program RFF_Simple
```

The code compiles no problem, but running it yields the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM9gU.jpg

Yes I that is a print screen.

I don't even know where to start with this one.

Comment: Please **always** copy the error message into your question. The picture is not acceptable. The error message is one of the most important things in your question and must be searchable. You should also update the title with the actual error and not the code. `severe(408)` tells nothing.  *subscript is larger than the upper bound* tells much more. Also, you should report which compiler you are using, otherwise the error code 408 is completely useless. Please read [ask].

Comment: If you don't know how to copy text from the Windows console, search the internet https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/copy-to-the-clipboard-from-the-windows-command-prompt/

Comment: Dude I can't copy the text the cmd window flashes for a millisecond and then closes.

Comment: How did you do the screenshot then? Search the internet how to stop this flashing, this is quite a basic thing dude (hint - insert a read at the and or run it from the terminal from the beginning). You could **at least** copy the main content by hand. I was able  to do that when editing the title, you should have done it yourself.

Comment: lol coordination and quick reflexes is how I got the screenshot. I'll look into how to stop the flashing, that could be useful to know. You have a link?

Comment: Are you really so lazy you can't even search yourself? Then read my comment above for a hint. I don't even know how you are executing it, so how can I point you to an exact solution? I can only assume you are using some IDE.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that you increment `index` after each successful read. After the last successful read we have `index=length`. You then add 1 to `index` and then attempt to read `numbers(length+1)` which results in a bounds violation. Rather than looping with a `do while` you can just use a regular do loop since we know the number of lines to read.

```
do index = 1, length
   read(lun,*) numbers(index)
enddo
```

You could also test whether `index` is greater than `length` and bail out of the loop.

Comment: Weird. You must be right. The do loop works, but just for my sake I'm gonna look into the index check in the while loop. Thanks.